# How to using two buttons triggering two different api's change the same div content

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two buttons each of which onClick call different API endpoint. How do I code it in REACT so the same DIV content is rendered with plain JSON response (for now for simplicity) base on the button clicked ? Currently I'm using variable (ping) from the first api call 'getPing' but I'd want div content to be changed base on either of the two ping or ping2 depends on the button clicked.

```
function CoingeckoApiPage2() {
    const [ping,setPing] = useState('')
    const getPing = () => {
    axios.get(CoinGeckoPing()).then(
        res => (
            console.log(res.data),
            setPing(res.data)
        )
    
    )}

    const [ping2,setPing2] = useState('')
    const getPing2 = () => {
    axios.get(CoinGeckoCurrencies()).then(
        res => (
            console.log(res.data),
            setPing(res.data)
        )
    
    )}        

    return (
            <div>


      <Button onClick={getPing} variant="contained" color="bluecustom" > GET1</Button>         
      <Button onClick={getPing2} variant="contained" color="bluecustom">GET2</Button>
                                         
          <div>{JSON.stringify(ping)}</div>                               
            </div>
    )
}

export default CoingeckoApiPage2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to using two buttons triggering two different api's change the same div content

Why not to use only one, common `state` and just overwrite it when one of the requests resolves?

```
const [commonState, setCommonState] = useState('');

axios.get(CoinGeckoPing()).then(
    res => (
        setCommonState(res.data);
    )
)

axios.get(CoinGeckoCurrencies()).then(
    res => (
        setCommonState(res.data);
    )
)

<div>{JSON.stringify(commonState)}</div>
```